# How to build a Haskell list inside a monad lazily?

Tags: haskell, monads

Consider the following two nearly identical functions:

```
buildList 0 = []
buildList n = n : buildList (n - 1)

buildListM 0 = return []
buildListM n = buildListM (n - 1) >>= return . (n :)
```

The laziness aspect of Haskell allows for `buildList` to generate the list without much overhead in memory because it generates the head of the list and then builds the tail.

But the monadic version `buildListM` seems to use more memory as `n` gets larger because it must build the tail first and then prepend the head.

Is this a good way to build lists inside monads, or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: If your list generation is itself a pure computation, use `let`. If it is the result of a monadic operation, you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: "It must build the tail first and then prepend the head" -- this claim depends on the monad. For example, the `State` monad leaves `buildListM` perfectly efficient -- try leaving off the base case and watch the numbers scream by after you `evalState (buildListM 0) ()`.

Comment: As others have stated, the semantics of monadic computation depend on the monad. But if the monad in particular is one with too-strict bind operator, you will still run into the issue you have described. It is well known that the default `sequence` and friends have O(n^2) complexity for certain too-strict monads. For a fairly in depth analysis of this problem occurring in the real world, and how it was solved, see [here](https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-Pipes-Library/issues/100). Spoiler: the solution is to roll your own efficient implementation of sequence/mapM/replicateM, etc.

Comment: Thanks. These are really good explanations to counter the assumption I had.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many `Monads` (e.g., `IO`, strict `ST s`, strict `State s`) are "strict", in that `>>=` is strict in its left operand. Others, most notably `Identity` but also `(->) a`, lazy `State s`, lazy `Writer q`, lazy `ST s`, are "lazy" in the sense that `>>=` is not strict in its left operand. Consider applying `toListM` in the `Identity` monad:

```
buildListM 0 = return []
buildListM n = buildListM (n - 1) >>= return . (n :)
```

Here, `return = Identity` and `Identity m >>= f = f m`, so

```
buildListM 0 = Identity []
buildListM n = Identity . (n :) $ runIdentity (buildListM (n - 1))
             = Identity (n : runIdentity (buildListM (n - 1)))
```

Since `Identity` and `runIdentity` are complete no-ops at runtime, `buildListM` is actually the same as `buildList` when run in the `Identity` monad. It's the particular monad, not the monadic nature, that makes things strict.

You can sometimes do lazy things in "strict" monads in one of two ways:

1. Cheat using `unsafeInterleaveIO` or `unsafeInterleaveST`.
2. Use the more powerful `MonadFix` abstraction which lets you get hold of the result of a computation before it's been executed, but that will fail on you if you access such a result before it's available.